# Git Commit policy in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, git-commit

We are currently using Visual Studio On-line and TFS. As a company policy we want to enforce a commit to have work item assigned, but we can't find a way to enforce this, Is anyone know to enforce commit policy in TFS with GIT repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported out of the box.

It is however on the product teams backlog and you should vote for it on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, 2015 (not sure about earlier versions) has support for branch policies - referenced item, required reviewers, etc